# W3C validator does not pass <nobr> tag

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I'm using this piece of code:

```
<div class="home_notizia_page_riassunto">
   <?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>">  <nobr>- <span style="color:red;"> Leggi tutto </span></nobr></a>
</div>
```

But I get this errore in W3C validator:

> Element `nobr` not allowed as child of element `a` in this context.

I tried to put `nobr` in many place but the problem still remains the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: It would help to know which HTML you validated against

Comment: I used https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`<nobr>` tag is deprecated in HTML 5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#nobr). Use CSS `white-space` instead:

```php
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>">
     <span style="white-space: nowrap">- <span style="color:red;"> Leggi tutto </span>
     </span>
 </a>
```

From [the W3 wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space):

> The white-space property specifies how white-space inside an element
>   is handled.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug -- but in the HTML 5 spec, more than in the validator. W3C needs to fix the spec. `<nobr>` should properly be in the spec, because it is needed to convey important semantic information: namely that the enclosed content is semantically a single unit, which should not be split by line breaks.

Comment: This isn't the place to air your grievances about the HTML spec.

Comment: Oh, I'm being restrained. I could go on. E.g., do you think a hyphen is "white-space?"